# Why has the destructor been called only once?

Tags: c++, destructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {   
        printf("construct ..\n");
    }   

    ~Test()
    {   
        printf("destruct...\n");
    }   
};

Test Get()
{
    Test t = Test();
    return t;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test t = Get();
    return 0;
}
```

the console output is :

```
$ g++ -g -Wall -O0 testdestructor.cc
$ ./a.out
```

construct ..

destruct...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose the reason is *return value optimization* in 'Get'.

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Actually your code is not the standard example, but maybe your compiler applies it here as well.

Answer (score 10):

Its because of copy-elision by the compiler when you return the value from the function. In this case, the copy-elision is called RVO  - Return Value Optimization.

See these

- [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)
- [Copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)

Answer (score 6):

Compiler optimizations.

On other compilers/optimization settings, it might get called more than once.

See this compile: http://codepad.org/8kiVC3MM

> Output:
>   1 construct ..
>   2 destruct...
>   3 destruct...
>   4 destruct...
>   5 destruct...

Note that the defined constructor wasn't called all those times because the compiler-generated copy constructor was called instead.

See this compile: http://codepad.org/cx7tDVDV

... where I defined an extra copy constructor on top of your code:

```
Test(const Test& other)
{
    printf("cctor\n");
}
```

> Output:
>   1 construct ..
>   2 cctor
>   3 destruct...
>   4 cctor
>   5 destruct...
>   6 cctor
>   7 destruct...
>   8 destruct...

Answer (score 2):

It's called return value optimization, or [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Answer (score 2):

Try `g++ -fno-elide-constructors` (and define a copy constructor that prints a message).