# copy constructor and operator = in c++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, copy-constructor

I have a question about the following code:

let's say I have a class P that has a copy constructor and a regular constructor the receives one string value.

I have the following code:

```
P doSomething(){
   P p("myValue");
   return p;
}

int main(){
    P m=doSomething();
    return 1;
}
```

1. why isn't copy constructor invoked at the `return p` of the `doSomething()` function?
2. the call `P m=doSomething()` - does it suppose to call the copy constructor or the operator=?
3. in case it's operator =, what is the difference of this code and the following:

   ```
   P new_val=("newVal");
   p m=new_val;
   ```

(i know here the call is for copy constructor)

Thanks,
Mary

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why has the destructor been called only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422114/why-has-the-destructor-been-called-only-once)

Comment: Can you post your code for copy constructor defined in `class P`?

Comment: On initialization of a variable, always copy constructor is used, even though you are writing `=`. About why it's not used in your example, could be that the compiler has optimized your code?

Comment: my copy cosntructor is:
    P (const P & other):val(other.val){}

what meant in the assignment is:
    P m("ffff");
    P t=m;
as i understand here there is a call for copy constructor
what I'm trying to understand why in the code 
    p m=doSomething();
there is no call.

Answer (score 2):

- why isn't copy constructor invoked at the return p of the doSomething() function?

The standard allows this copy to be elided. Google for [N]RVO. On certain compilers this happens only when optimizing, on others it is part of the calling conventions and thus happens always.

- the call P m=doSomething() - does it suppose to call the copy constructor or the operator=?

`T t = x;` is "syntactic sugar" (in the sense that the `T(x)` is happening implicitly) for `T t(T(x))` and thus has -- despite the `=` -- nothing to do with `operator=`. Note that also here the additional temporary may be elided, thus no copy ctor is called.

- in case it's operator =, what is the difference of this code and the following:

This code makes no sense, what did you really mean?

```
P new=("newVal");
p m=new;
```

Comment: Re point 2, it's not quite syntactic sugar: the conversion in `T t = x` is implicit (and `explicit` constructors will not be considered); the conversion in your rewrite is explicit.  (It's actually possible to write code where both would be legal, but have different semantics.  Such code is probably best avoided, however.)

Comment: Copy-initialization and direct initialization aren't entirely equivalent. The latter works even with an `explicit` copy constructor, the former doesn't.

Comment: @JamesKanze: therefore the quotes around it, I try to make it a  bit cleared in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small sample for demonstration.

```
void print(char* text, int ident)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ident ; i++)
    {
        printf("   ");
    } // end for

    fprintf(stdout, text);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

class P
{
public:
    char* _str;

    P (P& arg)
    {
        print("copy constructor", 2);
        arg._str = this->_str;
    }

    P (char* str)
    {
        print("constructor", 2);
        _str = str;
    }
};

P doSomething(){
    print("do something - function", 1);
    P p("myValue");
    print("before return p", 1);
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    print("start", 0);
    P m=doSomething();
    print("stop - call return", 0);
    return 1;
}
```

this returns

```
start
   do something - function
      constructor
   before return p
      copy constructor
stop - call return
```

so copy constructor WILL BE CALLED

Answer (score -2):

> 1) why isn't copy constructor invoked at the "return p" of the doSomething() function?

it should - try printing something to the console in the copy c-tor to see if it is really running.

> 2) the call P m=doSomething() - does it suppose to call the copy constructor or the operator=?

should call the operator=. again, use the debug message print from within the method to check

> 3) in case it's operator =, what is the difference of this code and the following:
>   P new=("newVal"); p m=new; (i know here the call is for copy constructor)

did you miss something on the code snippet? i think it won't compile

Comment: t should - try printing something to the console in the copy c-tor to see if it is really running.   - I did, it doesn't print anything