# Why a function parameter(Myclass) can have L and R values but same return type (Myclass) can only returns R value?

Tags: c++, function, reference, pass-by-reference, declaration

I am having a hard time understanding of this concept.
I can send L value and R value as a parameter in

`Myclass foo(Myclass)`

but can not return L and R value from that function. Only R values comes out.

I want to know why this happens?

```
class Myclass {};

Myclass fooReturnsL(Myclass b)
{
    Myclass a;
    return a;
}

Myclass fooReturnsR(Myclass b)
{
    return Myclass{};
}

int main()
{
    Myclass var_Myclass;

    Myclass& lref = fooReturnsL(var_Myclass); // sythax error
    Myclass& lref = fooReturnsL(Myclass{}); // sythax error

    Myclass&& rref = fooReturnsR(var_Myclass); // no error  
    Myclass&& rref = fooReturnsR(Myclass{}); // no error
}
```

Is there anytime `Myclass fooReturnsL(Myclass b)` can return L value ?

Comment: To be an lvalue, it needs to have a name.  Return values do not have a name.

Comment: `fooReturnsL(var_Myclass)` and `fooReturnsL(Myclass{})` are pure rvalues (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). As such they cannot be bound to lvalue references as this would allow changing a temporary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
Myclass fooReturnsL(Myclass b)
{
    Myclass a;
    return a;
}
```

returns an object with automatic storage duration that will not be alive after exiting the function.

So you may not return a reference for a non-existent object.

You could declare the function for example like

```
Myclass &  fooReturnsL(Myclass &b)
{
    //... some other code
    return b;
}
```

and call it like

```
Myclass var_Myclass;

Myclass& lref = fooReturnsL(var_Myclass);
```

If you will try to return a reference to a local object with automatic storage duration from a function then program behavior will be undefined.

Consider the following demonstration program (provided that it will be compiled)

```
#include <iostream>

class Myclass 
{
public:
    ~Myclass() 
    { 
        std::cout << "Myclass::~Myclass() called\n" ;
    }
};

Myclass & fooReturnsL()
{
    Myclass a;
    return a;
}


int main()
{
    Myclass &t = fooReturnsL();

    std::cout << "Press any key to continue...";
}
```

The program output is

```
Myclass::~Myclass() called
Press any key to continue...
```

As you can see the object declared in the function was destroyed. So the reference is a dangling reference.

Comment: when i create an object `Myclass obj;` inside `Myclass& foo(Myclass a)`  function and `return obj` , `obj` have an automatic storage duration and it will not be alive after function executed but i can bind with L value reference in main() too, like `Myclass& lref = foo(var_Myclass)`

Comment: @UPinar Such a code has undefined behavior.

Comment: 1 more question when send var_Myclass or Myclass{} as a parameter copy ctor called right ? if function like this `Myclass& foo(Myclass)`

Comment: @UPinar For a temporary object used as an argument expression the copy constructor can be omitted. It is called copy constructor elision.

Comment: ohh cool so a Myclass object created directly inside foo() functions stack, like a temp object

Comment: @UPinar When the function exits it is destroyed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890528/copy-constructor-elision this explains well. Thank you again :)